# Python matplotlib into barchart

Tags: python

I have 2 python file with 1 csv file.

I'm trying to accumulate All the Visitors from 2000 - 2009 from each countries and Select The Top 3 country as it will show up the barchart of the Top 3 Country

The Error I having is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ASP/pythonProjectDA_YODA/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    countries=Countries("2000","2009","China","Japan")
  File "C:\ASP\pythonProjectDA_YODA\countries.py", line 8, in __init__
    dfVisitor.index=pd.to_datetime(dfVisitor.index)
  File "C:\Users\65965\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 812, in to_datetime
    result = convert_listlike(arg, format, name=arg.name)
  File "C:\Users\65965\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 459, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    result, tz_parsed = objects_to_datetime64ns(
  File "C:\Users\65965\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 2044, in objects_to_datetime64ns
    result, tz_parsed = tslib.array_to_datetime(
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 352, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 579, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 718, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 552, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
TypeError: <class 'tuple'> is not convertible to datetime
```

I have no idea what this means cus this is still first time for me to learn this.

The main.py file code is stated below :

```
**from countries import Countries
countries=Countries("ListedCountries.csv","2000","2009","China","Japan")
countries.top3()
countries.drawchart()**

Another Python file is stated below as well :

**import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
class Countries:
  def __init__(self,syear,eyear,scountries,ecountries):
      dfVisitor=pd.read_csv("ListedCountries.csv")
      dfVisitor.index=pd.to_datetime(dfVisitor.index)
      dfVisitor.columns=dfVisitor.colums.str.strip()
      dfOther=dfVisitor.loc[syear:eyear, scountries:ecountries]
      dfOtherTotal=dfOther.sum()
      self.dfOtherTotalSorted=dfOtherTotal.sort_values(ascending=False)
      print(self.dfOtherTotalSorted)
  def top3(self):
      value=self.dfOtherTotalSorted.to_dict()
      c=1
      print("Top 3 countries in the region over a span of 10 years")
      for x, y in value.items():
          if c<=3:
              print(c,x,y)
              c+=1 #c=c+1
      if len(value)>0:
          return True
      else:
          return False
  def drawchart(self):
      ps=self.dfOtherTotalSorted
      index=np.arrange(len(ps.index))
      plt.xlabel("No. of Visitors in 10 years visit Singapore",fontsize=10)
      plt.ylabel((1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000), fontsize=15)
      plt.xticks(index,ps.index,fontsize=15, rotation=90)
      plt.title("Total visitors from 2000 to 2009 in Singapore")
      plt.bar(ps.index,ps.values)
      plt.show()**
```

Lastly i have is the CSV.file :

```
**Japan,HongKong,China,Taiwan,Korea
 2000 Jan,72,131,16,288,38,887,19,329,32,621
 2000 Feb,71,245,28,265,45,148,30,528,28,932
 2000 Mar,91,844,21,513,30,644,22,934,30,682
 2000 Apr,60,540,29,308,36,511,27,737,27,237
 2000 May,62,152,20,822,37,934,23,635,30,739
 2000 Jun,67,977,22,011,30,706,26,582,25,318
 2000 Jul,84,634,30,218,36,148,35,570,32,960
 2000 Aug,101,785,31,963,41,162,30,732,34,877
 2000 Sep,89,417,20,566,31,239,19,824,23,207
 2000 Oct,73,383,21,512,35,195,17,685,28,185
 2000 Nov,80,889,21,326,32,999,17,034,31,169
 2000 Dec,73,898,22,183,37,762,19,314,28,426
 2001 Jan,65,381,27,778,56,460,20,418,32,727
 2001 Feb,72,335,18,442,36,157,20,078,32,777
 2001 Mar,85,655,27,025,30,320,16,438,32,441
 2001 Apr,58,348,25,816,37,542,19,756,30,150
 2001 May,58,984,19,806,41,999,16,381,28,842
 2001 Jun,64,582,23,752,31,882,19,445,26,914
 2001 Jul,76,373,24,929,45,570,25,185,34,830
 2001 Aug,92,508,28,515,51,208,21,981,35,899
 2001 Sep,69,850,20,024,34,386,15,218,23,526
 2001 Oct,35,970,19,363,42,586,14,259,24,125
 2001 Nov,32,294,18,583,41,208,15,219,29,452
 2001 Dec,43,483,22,124,48,080,17,709,27,400
 2002 Jan,47,447,16,630,50,303,18,995,38,613
 2002 Feb,49,583,26,760,81,649,21,463,30,745
 2002 Mar,68,549,24,043,42,728,16,038,38,393
 2002 Apr,49,149,21,771,63,880,17,554,32,704
 2002 May,50,563,23,490,56,486,16,570,27,807
 2002 Jun,54,892,22,965,41,186,17,251,27,519
 2002 Jul,66,566,26,488,51,147,25,238,32,353
 2002 Aug,85,655,26,513,62,699,22,147,39,236
 2002 Sep,77,884,18,914,47,217,13,553,21,472
 2002 Oct,58,489,21,025,57,693,15,730,28,827
 2002 Nov,54,294,17,425,56,422,11,981,28,758
 2002 Dec,60,338,19,941,58,683,12,796,24,591
 2003 Jan,53,131,17,336,62,454,15,826,34,976
 2003 Feb,50,469,24,563,89,704,17,940,32,707
 2003 Mar,54,497,16,460,54,063,11,498,25,186
 2003 Apr,12,501,4,808,23,002,2,531,2,890
 2003 May,7,056,5,510,3,994,1,283,2,552
 2003 Jun,14,051,16,426,8,405,5,412,8,477
 2003 Jul,28,636,29,541,20,989,18,298,25,714
 2003 Aug,43,016,34,391,52,847,19,466,30,591
 2003 Sep,47,623,17,839,57,716,13,190,20,942
 2003 Oct,38,418,19,234,56,700,14,982,24,175
 2003 Nov,37,630,18,368,67,541,12,271,29,059
 2003 Dec,47,021,21,778,71,068,12,233,24,125
 2004 Jan,39,191,22,763,79,717,17,014,30,255
 2004 Feb,43,760,17,189,50,903,13,918,29,835
 2004 Mar,53,022,18,564,53,481,13,060,25,853
 2004 Apr,38,801,24,158,75,068,13,484,26,713
 2004 May,43,714,23,922,70,021,13,963,31,482
 2004 Jun,44,112,21,679,63,014,15,181,29,912
 2004 Jul,56,066,27,380,92,649,21,955,35,568
 2004 Aug,66,617,30,887,90,212,19,708,38,602
 2004 Sep,62,264,19,562,62,134,13,542,25,956
 2004 Oct,51,340,21,884,70,449,13,840,26,936
 2004 Nov,48,066,19,317,88,223,12,747,31,623
 2004 Dec,51,858,24,381,84,369,14,030,28,344
 2005 Jan,48,004,17,457,45,801,16,774,20,386
 2005 Feb,40,310,28,713,61,601,19,104,24,531
 2005 Mar,52,225,31,089,52,249,15,669,23,476
 2005 Apr,41,599,23,614,68,775,16,345,28,923
 2005 May,43,968,25,187,62,872,16,019,28,927
 2005 Jun,43,020,23,843,61,150,16,710,32,366
 2005 Jul,49,791,35,295,93,889,27,702,42,961
 2005 Aug,61,522,38,649,101,134,22,950,42,791
 2005 Sep,57,085,23,649,67,061,15,670,25,572
 2005 Oct,49,532,22,996,74,501,17,754,30,060
 2005 Nov,50,402,20,552,88,704,14,094,31,277
 2005 Dec,50,994,22,770,79,945,15,123,32,803
 2006 Jan,45,402,23,587,81,734,19,898,40,604
 2006 Feb,44,695,22,743,96,562,17,723,40,835
 2006 Mar,62,353,21,726,91,092,16,227,36,144
 2006 Apr,41,269,28,836,97,423,17,657,31,780
 2006 May,42,907,24,008,78,594,15,410,34,236
 2006 Jun,43,153,23,998,71,213,17,393,36,327
 2006 Jul,52,407,28,265,113,127,27,109,45,685
 2006 Aug,62,970,30,672,103,459,23,438,44,846
 2006 Sep,51,284,20,463,63,550,15,350,29,315
 2006 Oct,47,552,21,801,70,690,17,087,35,025
 2006 Nov,52,047,22,845,88,343,15,953,43,791
 2006 Dec,48,367,22,530,81,414,16,218,36,134
 2007 Jan,49,959,19,559,76,116,17,156,46,756
 2007 Feb,46,920,26,025,111,934,23,307,31,464
 2007 Mar,58,843,22,361,79,239,16,091,42,071
 2007 Apr,37,962,29,338,99,136,15,343,32,219
 2007 May,38,813,25,261,85,198,14,952,34,408
 2007 Jun,41,289,25,551,77,239,16,868,38,027
 2007 Jul,49,234,31,990,108,881,24,849,46,123
 2007 Aug,58,288,32,177,114,463,21,028,45,910
 2007 Sep,54,186,22,902,76,181,16,276,30,265
 2007 Oct,51,825,23,224,83,831,14,426,33,383
 2007 Nov,53,784,22,638,103,906,13,742,43,965
 2007 Dec,53,411,21,084,97,832,14,118,39,701
 2008 Jan,52,973,19,817,108,486,16,342,50,432
 2008 Feb,47,449,27,263,121,031,17,829,40,998
 2008 Mar,57,364,27,600,98,180,13,778,39,683
 2008 Apr,36,301,20,232,107,639,13,944,33,946
 2008 May,42,382,22,867,86,785,14,276,36,412
 2008 Jun,40,879,23,055,70,565,13,146,35,998
 2008 Jul,47,659,28,218,105,528,19,398,39,614
 2008 Aug,53,699,26,847,91,325,16,923,42,338
 2008 Sep,48,771,20,765,66,582,12,303,25,914
 2008 Oct,47,736,20,016,76,836,13,503,30,930
 2008 Nov,48,225,19,197,79,096,12,535,24,445
 2008 Dec,47,602,22,238,66,689,11,947,22,308
 2009 Jan,38,382,23,399,105,144,15,986,25,516
 2009 Feb,42,807,19,720,80,037,12,744,27,387
 2009 Mar,46,797,21,290,91,275,12,542,20,759
 2009 Apr,31,633,28,587,86,525,11,970,21,323
 2009 May,29,800,21,529,52,058,11,602,21,854
 2009 Jun,28,060,21,703,41,650,11,486,20,991
 2009 Jul,46,633,33,382,72,326,17,351,30,389
 2009 Aug,50,698,36,218,86,530,17,490,32,332
 2009 Sep,52,561,21,509,59,588,10,443,15,714
 2009 Oct,43,247,25,512,83,273,13,208,16,069
 2009 Nov,38,949,20,525,90,358,11,900,19,620
 2009 Dec,40,420,21,046,87,983,10,039,20,033
112,551,37,334,126,870,29,368,52,654**
```

Comment: That's not a properly formed CSV file.  I'm guessing you expect there to be 6 columns, but pandas will see 11 columns, because the numbers all have embedded commas.  The individual numbers should not have commas in them.  If you must have commas, the fields need to be in quotes:  `2001 Sep,"69.850","20,024","34,386","15,218","23,526"`.

Comment: However, with the commas, pandas does not read them as integers -- it reads them as strings.  You need to remove the commas.

Comment: @TimRoberts so i have to remove the commas from the csv so the program can work and the barchart can be display ?

Comment: That's the big problem, yes, but there are others..  Your CSV also needs a label for the "Date" column, and you need to tell pandas to use that column.  I have made your program work, I will post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This code works, after you eliminate the embedded commas in the CSV file.  One other problem is you were trying to print "China":"Japan", but your columns were not in that order.  It needed to be "Japan":"China".  You also had several spelling errors (colums, arrange).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Countries(object):
    def __init__(self,filename,syear,eyear,scountries,ecountries):
        dfVisitor=pd.read_csv(filename)
        dfVisitor = dfVisitor.set_index('Date')
        dfVisitor.index=pd.to_datetime(dfVisitor.index)
        dfOther=dfVisitor.loc[syear:eyear, scountries:ecountries]
        dfOtherTotal=dfOther.sum()
        self.dfOtherTotalSorted=dfOtherTotal.sort_values(ascending=False)
        print(self.dfOtherTotalSorted)
    def top3(self):
        value=self.dfOtherTotalSorted.to_dict()
        print("Top 3 countries in the region over a span of 10 years")
        for x, y in list(value.items())[:3]:
            print(x,y)
    def drawchart(self):
        ps=self.dfOtherTotalSorted
        index=np.arange(len(ps.index))
        plt.xlabel("No. of Visitors in 10 years visit Singapore",fontsize=10)
        plt.ylabel((1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000), fontsize=15)
        plt.xticks(index,ps.index,fontsize=15, rotation=90)
        plt.title("Total visitors from 2000 to 2009 in Singapore")
        plt.bar(ps.index,ps.values)
        plt.show()

countries=Countries("ListedCountries.csv",pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01"),pd.to_datetime("2009-12-31"),"Japan","China")
countries.top3()
countries.drawchart()
```

Comment: After i have done all the csv commas it appear this ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ASP/pythonProjectDA_YODA/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    countries=Countries("ListCountries.csv",pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01"),pd.to_datetime("2009-12-31"),"Japan","China")
  File "C:/ASP/pythonProjectDA_YODA/main.py", line 8, in __init__
    dfVisitor = dfVisitor.set_index('Date')
  File "C:\Users\65965\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4551, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['Date'] are in the columns"

Comment: You are going to have to use your own brain here.  Did you notice that the title line in your CSV file doesn't include all of the columns?  Which one is missing?  What name did I use in mine?